# Miniprofiler always starts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-mini-profiler

I am using the [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) for a small ASP.Net web application. It is great when in development, but I would like a simple way to enable/disable it in production mode.

After reading [How to hide miniprofiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604595/how-to-hide-miniprofiler) and the tutorial, I came up with a method where I use a boolean in `Global.asax`:

```
bool useProfiler = false;
...
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    MiniProfiler profiler = null;

    if (useProfiler)
    {
        profiler = MiniProfiler.Start();
    }
}

protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    if (useProfiler)
    {
        MiniProfiler.Stop();
    }
}
```

But the problem is the MiniProfiler always starts, no matter what the value of `useProfiler` is.

Do I need to have some tests when calling `@MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()`as well?

Comment: Are you sure you're not calling `.Start()` anywhere else?  If it's not called, it's not going to instantiate a new `MiniProfiler`.

Comment: @JarrodDixon You were right: an example project was included in the package and was starting the profiler. See my answer.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem came from the fact that the `MiniProfiler.MVC` package has an example project included. A `MiniProfiler.cs` file is created in the `App_Start` folder, and starts with the web application.

Just removing this file solved the problem.

You can also delete `Views/Shared/_MINIPROFILER UPDATED Layout.cshtml` which is part of the example project.